# Items By Group added to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

Ok, not real sure how to explain this. But i have an existing custom post type with some custom fields that is working fine for detailed information about an event. what i am trying to do now is to add items from a pre-existing table to a certain category for this event.

like,
event1 has details
event one has three categories associated with it - FOOD, MUSIC, CRAFTS
i have a table that holds say vendors in it (add, edit delete already working).
i need to add a ajax type area to the admin side of the custom post type to be able to add any vendor to one of the categories.

so if i went to the event custom post type and wanted to add McDonalds to the food category for this weekends event, i would just use a select box and add it. I could also add Ozzy Osbourne to the Music category for this event. I could also add Wendys to the FOOD category.

hopefully this makes since.

thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: It's not really clear where you're having difficulties. Is it the ajax call?

Comment: relatively new to wp development.  used custom post types ui, etc to setup the custom post type.  able to add posts in the custom post type.  here is what i want.  i want to maintain a list of "items" that are categorized.  Foods would have values of McDonalds, Wendy's, Arbys, etc   Music would have Van Halen, Ozzy, etc.  each event i would be able to add X number of Food values (from a pulldown where i select foods) and X number of Music values (from a pulldown where i select music).

Comment: do i need to have a items table where all of these are stored along with a category table. Then have a EventItems table which would store which items have been added to the event?  how to code?

Answer (score 0):

From what I get in you question, I think you should create 3 taxonomies within the Custom Post Type UI plugin. Call these FOOD, MUSIC and CRAFTS, and attach them to the custom post type you created.

Then you'll proceed to adding the specific items to each taxonomy. And these will automagically appear in your post-edit screen either as a text-field with autocomplete (if you create the taxonomy as non-hierarchical) or a list with checkboxes (if you create the taxonomy as hierarchical). And you're good to go.

Comment: thank you.  so no coding required it sounds like. i will try to create the taxonomies tonite and see how it goes.  thank you for your assistance.

Comment: have a go at it and come back to tell us if it worked out